# Evaluating an integral in 3 different intervals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_{-5}^{-2}\Big(\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-3x+1}\Big)^2dx\\+    \int_{1/6}^{1/3}\Big(\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-3x+1}\Big)^2dx\\+  \int_{6/5}^{3/2}\Big(\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-3x+1}\Big)^2dx\\$$

I don't think evaluating the complete integral and then substituting the limits is the way to go. There has got to be a better way which I am unable to think. Some hints. Thanks.
Please see that I need a pen and paper solution and I a sure that one exists.

So, finally I was able to crack it. Man, that integrand is good. I mean really good. Replacing $x$ by $\frac{1}{x-1}$ in the second integrand and $x$ by $1-\frac{1}{x}$ in the third give almost the same first integrand with the same limits. The only terms that are extra are the differential of the substitution. And after that it is just a piece of cake.

Comment: Detailed steps for integration can be seen at http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%28x%5E2-x%29%5E2%2F%28x%5E2-3x%2B1%29%5E2&lbound=-5&ubound=-2

Comment: A bugged problem from Brilliant?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Really! could you please send me a link.